# exclude certain categories from posts on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a page which displays the latest posts, but I'm trying to exclude posts from certain categories. This is my code:

```
 <?php $categories = get_categories( $args ); ?>  
  <?php 
   $args = array( 'numberposts' => 2, 
 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date", 'exclude'=>"8");
   $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    echo '<div class="latest_new_posts">';
      foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >
 <div class="blog-date-news"><span><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></span></div>
 <div class="blog-container">
 <div class="news-blog-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></div>
 <div class="news-blog-excerpt"> <?php echo excerpt(500); ?> </div>

 </div>
</div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So I'm trying to exlude category ID 8 from it but it's still showing.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress does not know that you are trying to exclude Category, that exclude parameter is for post IDs.

To exclude categories from the Query. You use 'cat' parameter with MINUS sign i.e **'cat'=>'-8'**

Exclude Posts Belonging to Category ID 8

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 2, 
 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date", 'cat'=>'-8');
```

Source: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters