# Exclude certain posts from results

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, categories

I have the following list of arguments passed to WP_Query:

```
array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'terms' => ['18', '-36']
        )
    )
);
```

I was hoping that this would show posts that have the tag with ID 18 but not the tag with ID 36. However, the results I get show all posts that either have 18 or 36 or both the tags.

In short, the posts with tag 36 are not being excluded.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is another question that does something similar with categories: [exclude certain categories from posts on wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266718/exclude-certain-categories-from-posts-on-wordpress)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the WP_Query criteria to just look for specific ID/s, ie:

```php
array( 'tag__in' => array( 18 ) );
```